# Як організувати теґи про відмінювання?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Дислокація така:

#### Українською:

- Є відмінювання взагалі

  - відмінювання іменників, займенників і прикметників так і називається [відміна](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b0) або [відмінювання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f)
  - відмінювання дієслів називається [дієвідміна](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%96%d1%94%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b0) або [дієвідмінювання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%96%d1%94%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f)

#### Англійською [ще складніше](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection#Declension_and_conjugation):

- є [inflection](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inflection)

  - Inflecting a noun, pronoun, adjective, article or determiner is known as declining it. [declension](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/declension)
  - Inflecting a verb is called conjugating it. [conjugation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugation) The affixes may express tense, mood, voice, or aspect.

Проблема:

1. Плодити купу теґів не хочеться, я хотів би поки що робити один теґ
2. пересічний користувач не знає точної різниці між вищезгаданими термінами
3. запитання все одно будуть додатково позначені тегами на зразок [іменники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%96%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8), тому навіть якщо матимемо один-єдиний теґ (наприклад, [відмінювання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f)), то цього може бути достатньо.
4. **Але** якщо сайт виросте, і в якийсь час буде сотні запитань, які мають спільний теґ, то буде дуже важко «розклеїти» один теґ на декілька

Запитання: як зробити правильно?

Answer (score 1):

- **відмінки** (створити) ← [noun-cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noun-cases), [cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases)¹, [declension](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/declension), [відмінювання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f)
- **дієвідмінювання** чи **дієвідміни** (створити) ← [conjugation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugation)
- <sub>**морфологія** (може) ← *morphology* (може), *inflection* (може) — загальна тема, якщо раптом комусь знадобиться усе відмінювання у широкому сенсі (можна не створювати, це радше прикидка — що будемо робити, якщо такі з'являться)</sub>

<sub>¹ Спочатку був думав, що [cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases) варто викинути, бо всього 1 вжиток ( і [noun-cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noun-cases) його повністю замінює) — але потім зрозумів, що відмінки є не лише в іменників (а й прикметники, числівники, займенники — іменні частини мови). Тож обидва будуть.</sub>

API test: a≈b c≈d­e.

Comment: @Artemix, Ви вирішили серйозну проблему, через яку я вже думав відмовлятися від голосу за цю схему. Немає сенсу робити «відмінювання-іменників», «відмінювання-прикметників», «відмінювання-числівників» і т.д. — лише одну загальну для всіх іменних частин мови. Але «відмінювання-іменних-частин-мови» задовго, а «відмінювання-імен» асоціюється з відмінюванням власних імен. А «відмінки» — супер, те, що треба (ІМХО).